# Gson in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson

I try to save data to object user by gson but have an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 911330 path $.assignedUser....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
                                                                            at com.loopj.andro
```

User class is:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("id")
    int id;

    @SerializedName("frontName")
    String name;

    @SerializedName("email")
    String email;

    @SerializedName("phoneNumber")
    String phoneNumber;

    @SerializedName("pesel")
    String pesel;

    @SerializedName("readableAdress")
    String adress;

    @SerializedName("avatar")
    String avatar;

    @SerializedName("city")
    String city;
}
```

and code where I use gson:

```
User user = new User();
String response = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
Gson gson = new Gson();
user = gson.fromJson(response, User.class);
```

Problem is in the structure of the string response?

Comment: What does your responseBody contain?  From the exception it is either malformed Json or not the correct schema for the object.

Comment: It would be great if you could print JSON and post it here, so we can judge. But exception hints malformed JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your JSON string is malformed. You can try this tool to validate it before parsing it with GSON. 
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

User Class:

```
public class UserData {   

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String pesel;
    private String address;
    private String avatar;
    private String city;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPesel() {
        return pesel;
    }

    public void setPesel(String pesel) {
        this.pesel = pesel;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

Now parse it like this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
Gson gson = new Gson();
response = gson.fromJson(br, User.class);
```